# Python strptime value error while everything looks correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I have a function which should get a date which I enter in an Entry box and use it to calculate some Data in that range like : from yyyy-mm-dd until yyyy-mm-dd

The data that I enter I used this format for everything YYYY-MM-DD (in the SQLITE database, function I have and also the entry box) 
here i will share the function which causes the error.

But still I get back this error:

```
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

```
  def weekly_cal():
        connect = sqlite3.connect('working_time_app.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        #fnishing i know it have a misspelling but this way should have no problem because i made that mistake
        #when i created the database and then was lazy to fix it so now this will be correct one
        cursor.execute("SELECT sum(fnishing - starting) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date BETWEEN ? and ?",
                       ((datetime.strptime(d_u_entry, "%Y-%m-%d")), (datetime.strptime(d_f_entry, "%Y-%m-%d"))))
        #d_u_entry and d_f_entry are the variables which hold the value of my entrybox

        sum_result = cursor.fetchall()


        show_weekly_cal_label = Label(cal_win, text=sum_result, font=("mv boli", 12), fg="white", bg="black")
        show_weekly_cal_label.grid(column=3, row=15, columnspan=5)



        connect.commit()
        connect.close()
```

Comment: `time data ''` means you're trying to parse an empty string at some point, but you need to cut this down to a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe did i edited my code correctly now ? i thought if i share the whole code i have would be easier to understand but after i read the a minimal reproducible example. from you i think this way should be correct !

Comment: What do you expect this `SELECT sum(fnishing - starting) FROM working_time_app_table.....` to be?

Comment: What *are* the values of `d_u_entry` and `d_f_entry`? Is one (or both) an empty string? The problem is likely *outside* the code you've shown if so.

Comment: well the select function should get a range of time between yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy-mm-dd which are dates then make the sum of (fnishing - starting ) which both are columns and have an amount of number in my database .@DinoCoderSaurus

Comment: i have two entry boxes which i write the dates in with this format yyyy-mm-dd .. then d_u_entry and d_f_entry both are variables which get back information from those entry boxes like : d_u_entry = entrybox.get() .. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Please do some debugging and narrow this down to the part *causing* the problem, not just where the error is thrown. It seems that those values are empty; find out *why*. Read e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `working_time_app_table.date` is stored in the database as a string formatted "YYYY-MM-DD", then you want the parameters sent to `WHERE  date between ? and ?` to be strings.

`strptime` is converting the entries to python date/time object. Since the entered data is already a string formatted "YYYY-MM-DD", there is no need for conversion to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your suggestions specially the ones who suggested debugging. I did debug was kind of a huge stress, but in the end finally i found my mistake !!!!

The error does not have to do with any kind of misspelling or Data type. The problem was wrongly locating the d_u_entry variable and d_f_entry variable. here i will post again the correct form of the code . Again thanks for all of you and your time that you invested in helping me. Also sorry for bothering you all !!!!

```
enter code here
```

```
  cursor.execute("SELECT total(finishing - starting) FROM working_time_app_table WHERE date BETWEEN ? and ?",
                   (d_f_entry, d_u_entry))
```

The problem was i was Entering the ending Date before the beginning !!!